# Divs placed relative to image on window resize (almost works)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 3 "pins" that are placed within a `div` (`#outerdiv`). The `div` has a `background-image` and the pins should be on the same spot on the background image at all the times when resizing window. **It works with `#pin1`**, but not with `#pin2` and `#pin3` (which uses the same code). The only difference is that `#pin1` is first in the html.

**EDIT:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v5hnfz0d/) and code snippet (scroll down)

[image]

When resizing window, `#pin1` works perfectly (is on the same spot on the background image). However, `#pin2` and `#pin3` and every other after that, is pushed a bit downwards and therefore not on the same spot anymore. However, it is still on the right horizontal axis.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateProductBg();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    updateProductBg();
});
function updateProductBg(){
    if($(window).width()/$(window).height() >=  2600/1450) {
        $('#outerdiv').css({'height':'100%','width':$(window).height()*(2600/1450)+'px', 'margin-left':-$('#outerdiv').width()/2+'px', 'left':'50%', 'top':'0', 'margin-top':0});
    } else {
        $('#outerdiv').css({'height':$(window).width()*(1450/2600)+'px', 'width':'100%', 'margin-left':0, 'left':0, 'top':'50%', 'margin-top': -$('#outerdiv').height()/2+'px'});
    }
}
```

```css
#outerdiv {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Luftaufnahmen_Nordseekueste_2013_05_by-RaBoe_314.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pin {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/WP_SOPA_sm_icon_identica_ffffff.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 33px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="pin1" class="pin" style="top:21%; left:38%;"></div>
    <div id="pin2" class="pin" style="top:13%; left:24.5%;"></div>
    <div id="pin3" class="pin" style="top:36%; left:26%;"></div>
</div>
```

`updateProductBg()` is used for making `#outerdiv` the same exact size as `background-image`. If you want to try it out yourself, change the `2600` and `1450` with your `width` and `height` of image.

Comment: Is there any chance you can show us a working example in http://jsfiddle.net? It's difficult to visualise the exact issue.

Comment: I've moved it to a code snipped for him. Just needs to be approved

Comment: Thanks guys. I added a jsfiddle. The one that Ionic added doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pin` is currently set to `position: relative;` this means `top` and `left` will offset the pin from where it painted on the page. To place them relatively to `#outerdiv` you need to make them `position: absolute;`.

In your original version `#pin1` works because it is output at the top left corner of `#outerdiv` before it is moved. The other two are positioned incorrectly because their position has been effected by the pins placed before them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateProductBg();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    updateProductBg();
});
function updateProductBg(){
    if($(window).width()/$(window).height() >=  2600/1450) {
        $('#outerdiv').css({'height':'100%','width':$(window).height()*(2600/1450)+'px', 'margin-left':-$('#outerdiv').width()/2+'px', 'left':'50%', 'top':'0', 'margin-top':0});
    } else {
        $('#outerdiv').css({'height':$(window).width()*(1450/2600)+'px', 'width':'100%', 'margin-left':0, 'left':0, 'top':'50%', 'margin-top': -$('#outerdiv').height()/2+'px'});
    }
}
```

```css
#outerdiv {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Luftaufnahmen_Nordseekueste_2013_05_by-RaBoe_314.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.pin {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/16/WP_SOPA_sm_icon_identica_ffffff.png);
    width: 32px;
    height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="outerdiv">
    <div id="pin1" class="pin" style="top:21%; left:38%;"></div>
    <div id="pin2" class="pin" style="top:13%; left:24.5%;"></div>
    <div id="pin3" class="pin" style="top:36%; left:26%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly! Can't believe it was that simple. Had misunderstood what `position: absolute` actually do.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the `position` for the rule `#outerdiv` to `position:relative`.

I'm sure this helps. I'm not able to reproduce it on my phone currently. Due to the fact that you haven't provided a running code example. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but it has to be 'absolute'-positioned, since it's not on top of my page normally.

Comment: Just to clarify, does it work with `position:relative`. If you, we may get a way to position it using another wrapping `div` or a `margin`?

Comment: No I don't think it will work. I am positioning my pins `relative` to the `absolute` div.